# auto submit form after input field has certain value (regex)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I have multiple input fields that each tab to the next. The last input fields value only allows values like `100A1` or `43D2` or `1B1`. My Regular expression for this is:

```
^[0-9]{1,3}[A-D][1-6]$
```

Now I want the form to be automatically submitted after any value like this. I use jQuery.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the problem then?

Comment: Maybe are you looking for a condition? Try with `.test()`. [See docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of `keyup` event on the input and trigger the form submit if the input value satisfies the regEx.

```
var pat = /^[0-9]{1,3}[A-D][1-6]$/;
$('#yourInputId').keyup(function(){
    if(pat.test($(this).val())){ //If the pattern is matched trigger form submit
     $('#yourFormId').trigger('submit');
    }
})
```

Comment: Hi. Thank u for the response, but it wont trigger the submit. I put your code inside a $(document).ready(function() {}.

Comment: @daniel Here is a small [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e2nm97se/). R you getting any errors?